# Why isn't OpenLDAP logging an error for my ldapsearch?

Tags: logging, ldap, ubuntu-12.10

I am trying to setup OpenLDap.  I am really unsure what I am doing and don't wish to post a general help me question without an answer.  I am interesting in getting more detailed log files so I can track down my problems.

when I run: `sudo ldapsearch -x -d8`

I get: `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

when I run: `sudo ldapsearch -x -d8 -v`

I get:

```
ldap_initialize( <DEFAULT> )
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

If have seen [this](http://beginlinux.com/server_training/server-managment-topics/1321-ldap-logging) but I don't have the file /etc/syslog.conf but modifying my rsyslog.conf in a similar way does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't specified a host or URI at all.  `ldapsearch` can't contact the server because one hasn't been provided.

- The openldap binaries do not currently support service discovery.
- The openldap client binaries binaries don't log.
- There is nothing to indicated that you are using SSL/TLS.
- You don't need `sudo` to do a search unless you're trying to be   `gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth`, in which case your URI should be `ldapi:///`.

Comment: So my answer is user input errors are not logged on the server level.  Do appreciate the help.  Updated the question in hopes that somebody else can use this useful information.